How to run SQL migrations to create tables in PostgreSQL from a .NET app without using EF Core in Docker?
I wanted to Docker Compose my .NET app with PostgreSQL.
I created a file with this connection string:
"DefaultConnection": "Host=employees.database;Port=5432;Database=EmployeeManager;Username=postgres;Password=admin"

I created this Docker file:
version: '3.4'

services:
  halfbitzadanie:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}xyz
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: xyz/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"

  employees.database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: employees.database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=EmployeeManager
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./.containers/employees-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

And then I run the app and it started throwing this error:

relation "employees" does not exist

Before docker, the app run just fine.
So I opened cmd and I typed:
docker exec -it employees.database psql -U postgres
\c EmployeeManager;

And I got:
postgres=# \c EmployeeManager;
You are now connected to database "EmployeeManager" as user "postgres".
EmployeeManager=#

Then
EmployeeManager-# \dt
Did not find any relations.
EmployeeManager-#

like no table was created and was inside the database.
I don't use Entity Framework. How to migrate and force database to create the tables?
I saw:
namespace Products.Api.Extensions;

public static class MigrationExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyMigrations(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        using IServiceScope scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();

        using ApplicationDbContext dbContext =
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }
}

How to migrate the database without EF Core?

How did you do it on your original, non-docker database?

i think i run the script in postgres

Then I would guess you have to do the same in your docker container, no?

The only thing the Postgres Docker image helps you with is initializing a new database. Then you can get it to run scripts to create tables etc. But if a database already exists, then you need to do your migration yourself using EF, scripts or whatever you like using.
